# how to get product original price from order object

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I've a Product with special price set to `8.00` with original price set to `12.00`

I'm trying to retrieve product's (item's) original price from order object like this:

```
$order = (new Mage_Sales_Model_Order)->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $price = $item->getPrice();
}
```

but, all these public methods:

`getPrice()`
   `getBasePrice()`
   `getPriceInclTax()`

seem to only return special price, i.e. `8.00`. How do I get original price, i.e. `12.00` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it. I was trying to get `Product` price from an `Item` object. An Item is a part of an Order and doesn't contain original price.

So, we have to first `getProduct` from this `Item`

```
$product = $item->getProduct()
```

and then,

```
$price = $product->getPrice()
```